# pip is giving conflict error while installing package

Tags: python, pip

While running `$ pip install <package>`, I am getting below error, in this case I am installing PyJWT and also checked for other packages to crosscheck. This happened after upgrading pip to 19.0.2 from 19.0.1.

Check below errors while running pip install PyJWT, requirement are already satisfied, but still I am getting error, please suggest how to fix it.

```
$ easy_install pip
```

for reinstalling the pip.

```
$ pip install PyJWT

Tejeshs-MacBook-Air:selenium_testing tejeshagrawal$ pip install PyJWT
Requirement already satisfied: PyJWT in
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.7.1) Error checking for
conflicts. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 2897, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map   File "/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 2691, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr) AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

**During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:**

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 2888, in _parsed_pkg_info
    return self._pkg_info   File "/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 2691, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr) AttributeError: _pkg_info

**During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:**

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py",
line 503, in _warn_about_conflicts
    package_set, _dep_info = check_install_conflicts(to_install)   File
"/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/check.py",
line 108, in check_install_conflicts
    package_set, _ = create_package_set_from_installed()   File "/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/check.py",
line 47, in create_package_set_from_installed
    package_set[name] = PackageDetails(dist.version, dist.requires())   File
"/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 2635, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map   File "/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 2899, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()   File "/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 2908, in _compute_dependencies
    for req in self._parsed_pkg_info.get_all('Requires-Dist') or []:   File
"/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 2890, in _parsed_pkg_info
    metadata = self.get_metadata(self.PKG_INFO)   File "/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 1410, in get_metadata
    value = self._get(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))   File "/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 1522, in _get
    with open(path, 'rb') as stream: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/~ip-18.1.dist-info/METADATA'
Tejeshs-MacBook-Air:selenium_testing tejeshagrawal$ pip freeze >
require.txt Could not parse requirement: -ip Exception: Traceback
(most recent call last):   File
"/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 2584, in version
    return self._version   File "/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 2691, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr) AttributeError: _version

**During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:**

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py",
line 179, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)   File "/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/freeze.py",
line 93, in run
    for line in freeze(**freeze_kwargs):   File "/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/freeze.py",
line 62, in freeze
    req = FrozenRequirement.from_dist(dist)   File "/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/freeze.py",
line 239, in from_dist
    req = dist.as_requirement()   File "/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 2716, in as_requirement
    if isinstance(self.parsed_version, packaging.version.Version):   File
"/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 2551, in parsed_version
    self._parsed_version = parse_version(self.version)   File "/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 2589, in version
    raise ValueError(tmpl % self.PKG_INFO, self) ValueError: ("Missing 'Version:' header and/or METADATA file", Unknown [unknown version]
(/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages))
```

Comment: I tried to delete cache files too from folder ~/Library/Caches/pip
still it is giving error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like your problem is similar or the same as [this bug](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6194) which was ironically [fixed in 19.0.2](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/6225). The problem is somewhere along the line you tried to install a module and it failed. `pip` didn't properly clean up after itself and left a package in a broken state.

The solution seems to be to find any directories starting with `-` in your `site-packages` directory (`/Users/tejeshagrawal/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages` in your case) and rename them to what they should be. eg. if you find `-yJWT-1.0.dist-info` then you should rename it to `PyJWT-1.0.dist-info`. If you're not sure what it's real name should be then look for the `Name` value in `-yJWT-1.0.dist-info/METADATA`. NB. I just used `PyJWT` as an example, it might not be the package(s) that is/are broken. After that pip should be able to get up and running again.

Comment: I was not able to find -yJWT-1.0.dist-info and other folders with "-" keyword, and accidentally I removed _vendor folder from the pip folder. to fix the issue upgraded python3 with $ brew upgrade python3, which then it upgraded to python-3.7.2_2. then I tired to run $ pip, it gave me -bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/bin/python3.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory.
again i installed python3 by $ brew install python3
and to install pip using
sudo python3 -m pip install pip setuptools, 
it installed pip3 but still it is giving me again conflict error

Comment: yes the solution is correct, I found one folder with -ip-18.1.dist-info/ , which I renamed it to ip-18.1.dist-info/ and this didn't solve the issue, so I looked at the error closely, and it should be pip-18.1.dist-info/ so again I renamed it to pip-18.1.dist-info/. 
$mv ip-18.1.dist-info/ pip-18.1.dist-info/
now it is not giving error, thank you for the solution

Comment: In Win7 it starts with a ~ (tilde).

Answer (score 1):

Complementary finding:
Using @Dunes answer, couldn't fix the file name so I ended-up unninstalling every package from PIP

**PowerShell** `pip uninstall -y (pip freeze)`

When the loop broke on the Plackage "Plotly" I found the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install the package pip-conflict-checker:

```
pip install pip-conflict-checker
```

and then run the command:

```
pipconflictchecker
```

this will show you the packages that cause troubles

Comment: I tried to run it, it is not giving me package name that causes trouble

Comment: I can't install pip-conflict-checker because I get conflicts haha fml

Comment: It does not show anything even there were conflicts

Answer (score -1):

You can create a virtual environment as well by following this link:-              https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands

```
    Step 1: conda create -n myenv python=3.7.4
    Step 2: conda activate myenv
    Step 3: pip install package_name
```

This helps to manage an individual conda environment to manage packages.